# Link location change based on select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file manager that i want to try and encourage users to download. I've seen sites do something similar but don't know what its called to try and search for a similar post.

[image]

This is like what i want. If the "Use Manager" is ticked it will give them a different URL to when it is un-ticked.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you would want to do is handle a click event on your checkbox and according to it's value (checked or unchecked), modify the `href` property of the "Download Now" link.

```
$( "#your_checkbox" ).on( "click", function(){
  var link = "http://some_link.com"; // default link for unchecked
  if ( $(this).is( ":checked" ) ){
    link = "http://some_other_link.com"; // modified link for checked
  }
  $( "#your_download_btn" ).attr( "href", link ); // setting the href
});
```

Here is a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lixroz/cR9b4/3/).

Comment: Thanks that looks great, What do i actually put on the ahref? does it need a class or something to work? Would you mind doing a jsfiddle?

Comment: You would put the correct url depending on the initial state of the checkbox

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i don't really understand what you mean? So i have a normal a href linking to my download page but how does that link know if the tick box is ticked? Do i need to tell it to look in the script you've written or something ?

Comment: You know if the checkbox is marked because you have placed it in your html file... If it's initial state is checked (in the original HTML file), then pass your href as if it was checked, if not - place the other value.

Comment: @Exoon - I've added a simple example fiddle. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks thats what i did understand the id="the_link" bit didn't thanks for the help

Comment: Hey, Ive just been testing it, And the first time you visit the site it will ignore the JS, Check this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cR9b4/4/ - The link is for ask, it dosen't check if its check or unchecked for the first time but then if u uncheck it manually it will work. Any ideas?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments for my code example in my answer, you have to place the default `href` in the JS code too. You just changed the HMTL and not the JS. Essentially, your HTML link doesn't even need an `href` parameter as the JS code will do all of the work.

Comment: You'll need to follow and understand the code - you won't be able to just copy paste my example without knowing what it's doing.

Comment: Yeah i understand, Is it possible to ignore the actual link though so i can hide the location? I want to just put # in the ahref part.

Comment: Sure you can. Just place `#` in the `href` and the JS will decide what link to use according to the checkbox. You won't be able to completely hide the location because all of the JS code is visible to the user. Anyone with minimal knowledge about JS and web browsers will be able to see your JS.

Comment: But check the JSFiddle i linked, i made the actual href ask.com and it will always ignore the JS and load ask.com unless u actually uncheck and recheck the box. Same if i make it a #

Comment: @Exoon - Yes. Please read my comments and my code I posted *in my answer* again. I have already explained to you why this is happening.

Comment: But you just said it dosen't matter what the href is. Say i want it to open Google.com and Stackoverflow but want the href to display ask.com  . I never want to open ask.com, Just display that link. Are you saying you already explained that as i can't see it :( all i see you say is it dosen't matter what the href is.... but it does seem to matter as it keeps opening ask when it should open google.com

Comment: Oh... I am sorry, you are correct you will need to set the initial href. If you *really* don't want to set in the HMTL, you could always set it initially with JS: `$("#the_link").attr( "href", "http://ask.com")`. It sounds a little bit like you're trying to trick your users into clicking a fake link though... I really hope that is not what you're planning to do.

Comment: Thanks, thought i was going mad i've read your text about 30 times just to make sure lol. Anyway, I'm not trying to trick users i just want to show # for the link so people can't easily right click and copy the link. I know it will be in the source but thats hassle. Any ideas how to show a #. Its showing the actual link at the moment.

Comment: You could place a `#` in the HTML and then when the link is clicked, you can check if the `#` is present and only then redirect the users with `window.open()`.

Answer (score 2):

### Plain JavaScript:

```
// Get DOM objects ready
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    downloadButton = document.querySelector('a#download');

// Set up function to change URL
function chooseUrl() {
    var url =
        checkbox.checked ? 'http://example.com/default_download' : 'http://example.com/secondary_download';

    downloadButton.setAttribute('href', url);
}

// Change URL on checkbox value change
checkbox.addEventListener('change', chooseUrl);

// Run chooseUrl once to set initial value
chooseUrl();
```

[**Demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerEich/A5Hz3/)

---

### JavaScript + jQuery:

```
// Get jQuery-wrapped DOM objects ready
var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    downloadButton = $('a#download');

// Set up function to change URL
function chooseUrl() {
    var url =
        checkbox.is(':checked') ? 'http://example.com/default_download' : 'http://example.com/secondary_download';

    downloadButton.attr('href', url);
}

// Change URL on checkbox value change
checkbox.on('change', chooseUrl);

// Run chooseUrl once to set initial value
chooseUrl();
```

[**Demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerEich/PZ2jL/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple jQuery example for exactly what your trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/9g6Wn/2/

```
var btn = $('#btn1');
var chk = $('#chk1');

btn.click(function () {
    if (chk.is(':checked') == true) {   // if the checkbox is checked
        location.assign('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc');
    } else {
        location.assign('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `.is()` function in jQuery that you can use; it checks if a state is active. For example, for anchor tags (`<a>`), you can have `:hover` to change its hover state. Similarly, for check boxes (`<input type='checkbox' />`), you can check the `:checked` state.

Since `href` is an attribute of the `<a>` tag, you can use

```
  $("#yourButtonThing").attr("href","newlink");
```

to change the link.

Here's a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yYWT/